# Do aliases compound upon each other? Is this all shells, does cmder compound aliases

Tags: alias, conemu, cmder

If I have an alias

```
la=ls -a
```

Can I then define a second alias after this that uses la

```
ll=la -l
```

I can't seem to get this to work with cmder (a Windows terminal emulator), which really just packages clink, ConEmu and some other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use nested aliases for cmd.exe.

However, you may create simple batch files, and one batch may call others.

Aliases work differently in different shells. In cmder you may define aliases in two ways:

- [Environment](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html) page in ConEmu [settings](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html)
- cmder's self-implemented `alias.bat`.

In any case, these [console aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057.aspx) are intended to be expanded by `cmd.exe` only, and you may see current list of defined aliases by executing in cmd.exe prompt

```
doskey /macros
```